# Spring MVC: @valid validation failed: going back to same page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

so,

I have Spring MVC, @Valid annotation.

On my home page I have search box, and some other stuf printed on the page which is read from database when we visit that page,

Now, when someone hits search button without putting anything the text box, .hasErrors() is true and return "index" which is same page.

the issue is that when I get back to the same page only the search box and search button and error message is there but everything else (the stuff read from database) is no more visible.

its probably because its not being served by same controller method, but what do I do to keep the page same?

Method populating the initial view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
        List<Ad> ads = adDao.getAll();
        model.addAttribute(ads);
        // this below is added for data binding.
        model.addAttribute("adSearchForm",new AdSearchForm());
        return "index";
    }
```

Method when someone tries to search

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchAds(Model model,@Valid @ModelAttribute("adSearchForm")  AdSearchForm adSearchForm,
                            BindingResult result,
                            HttpServletRequest request
                            ){
       if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "index";
       }
       List<Ad> ads =  adDao.searchAds(adSearchForm.getSearchTerm());
       model.addAttribute("searchresults",ads);
       return "searchResults";
    }
```

so when /search request is served, the data read by first method above is not visible on index page.

Comment: code is the best language we understand. please post yours

Comment: edited my questions, please have a look

Comment: where do you want the ads to be stored between requests? You can make it a session attribute with `@SessionAttributes`, or you can send it to the browser e.g. in hidden inputs and have it re-submitted with the next request. Or you can fetch from the DB again. But without doing one of these things, by default the ads list will be thrown away once the request/response completes

Comment: the data displayed on the first page has nothing to do with the request. I just want to keep the same page if the search box fails validation. so say If I have a million things being output on index page and if this validation fails that means I have to do one of things you have mentioned to make the page look same with an additional error message that they havn't put anything in the search box?

Comment: take example of amazon, if you dont type anything in the search box and you click the search button it comes right back to the same page...

Comment: Amazon is probably regenerating the page every time - I would guess if you wait a while and do that you'll get a slightly different page. Either way, you have to get the page data from *somewhere*, so yes, DB each time, or store it somewhere (browser, session) and then repopulate the model from there. In addition to `@SessionAttributes` you could also use a session-scoped bean. The easiest way would be to use `@SessionAttributes`, but if you have large amounts of data and/or lots of sessions, you may have scaling issues. If your DB is efficient enough, probably best to just re-run the query

Answer (score 1):

It just works this way. When i have more than 2/3 elements which i need to add to model and there is some form with binding result i usually create private method like this:

```
private void initModel(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("attr1", //getAttrFromDb
    model.addAttribute("attr2", //getAttrFromDb
    //more attributes...
}
```

And use it in GET and POST methods..

Comment: thanks, the question is do we need to handle it manually ourselves or there exists a "Spring Way" of doing this?